# How to create json array of object if the key already exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and query. I have an html form where the user can add or remove a group of fields. The group of fields contains 1 select and 3 inputs. The group of fields added have the same name of the previouses and so on.
What I'm trying to do is retrieve the value creating a structure like this.

```
{
    "colture1": [{
        "code_app": "A2",
        "long": "1",
        "lat": "103"
    }, {
        "code_app": "B34",
        "long": "11",
        "lat": "12"
    }],
    "colture2": [{
        "code_app": "GH3456",
        "long": "55",
        "lat": "90"
    }]
    // ....and so on
}
```

If the user selects a colture that already exist in the object, I'd like to add the others value in the same key as you can see in "colture1". My problem is here, I can't create an array where I can add the others value, now my function override the preovious values, It writes the last one values and it doesn't create an array.

This is my function

```
$('#create_json').on("click", function(e) {

  const json_data = {};
  var cat = "";
  for (const input of document.querySelectorAll(".card[mainBlock] select, .card[mainBlock] input")) {
    if (input.tagName === 'SELECT') {
      cat = input.value;
    } else {
      (json_data[cat] = json_data[cat] || {})[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json_data));
})
```

Here I can put a demo here https://jsfiddle.net/ou7h4f2m/3/. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier if you would deal with one section in each outer loop iteration (just on `.card[mainBlock]`), and then use an inner loop for processing the category and properties:

```
$('#create_json').on("click", function (e) { 
    const data = {};
    for (const section of document.querySelectorAll(".card[mainBlock]")) {
        const cat = section.querySelector("select").value;
        const obj = Object.assign(...Array.from(section.querySelectorAll("input"), input =>
            ({ [input.name]: input.value })
        ));
        (data[cat] = data[cat] || []).push(obj);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

I would not call your main variable `json_data`. It does not represent JSON, but a JavaScript object. JSON is what you get from calling `JSON.stringify`.